# Problems with blade echo

Tags: php, laravel

Sometimes blade echo doesn't print and I don't know why.

With this code visits are not printed

```php
@extends('layouts/base', ['title' => "$url->new"])

@section('content')
    <h1>Link Shortened !</h1>
    <a href="{{ $url->new }}">{{ $url->new }}</a>

    <h3>visits {{ $url->visits }}</h3>
@endsection
```

With this code (removing the space after visits) the number of visits is printed

```php
@extends('layouts/base', ['title' => "$url->new"])

@section('content')
    <h1>Link Shortened !</h1>
    <a href="{{ $url->new }}">{{ $url->new }}</a>

    <h3>visits {{ $url->visits}}</h3>
@endsection
```

Comment: Before removing is there any error message shown?

Comment: please replace `"$url->new"` to `$url->new` in `@extends`

Comment: @RakibulIslam No there is not message error !

Comment: @JinalSomaiya yes a little mistake !

Comment: Can you please “dd” the url object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work when you replace `"$url->new"` to `$url->new` in the `@extends` lines.

*(answered in the comments by @Jinal)*